# Loop through file and look up text with Regex

Tags: java, regex, selenium

I am using Selenium to test web-pages and want to make a simpler way to update the test-cases (not important for the problem).

I loop through lines now with this:

```
      driver.get("http://vg.no"); //open the web page
  try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("//Users//file.txt"));
        try {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(line)).click();; //find and click on the data specified in every line in the document
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("oops " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
```

Textfile content example now:

```
a[href*='//nyheter//meninger//']
img[class*='logo-red']
img[class*='article-image']
```

I want to rebuild it to a solution that start different commands based on regex expressions.
I try to get it to work this way:

```
vg.no //this will start driver.get("vg.no")
  img[class*='logo-red'] //this will start driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[class*='logo-red']")).click()
  img[class*='article-image']
ItAvisen.no 
  img[class*='article-image']
  img[class*='article-image']
```

Is there a way I can use regex to start dirrerent parts of the code based on content in the textfile, and use part of the content in the textfile as variables?

---

It works this way after feedback from cvester:

Finding matches for img[class*='logo-red']

```
                String regexp = "img\\[class\\*=\\'*\\'(.*)\\]";
                boolean match = line.matches(regexp);
```

Comment: As the project grows it will be difficult for you to maintain this file instead i would suggest u to use property files where u can save it in key value pairs.If you want more information kindly get back

Comment: I am thinking about using separate files and variables for values that is used often, but I think I have to solve this part first to be able to write out a full test just using the textfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it still be line based?
In that case you can just read line by line and use the `String.matches(String regex)` for each case you identify.

If you can specify more specific information I might be able to give you a better solution.

Comment: Yes, it will.
I will try to use that solution. Thanks.